# Angular-Wakanda $query start option not skipping elements

Tags: angularjs, wakanda

Looking at [Angular-Wakanda Documentation](https://wakanda.github.io/angular-wakanda/#/doc/api-reference/dataclass), I found `$query()` method.

I tried `$query({start:5})` and this query is not skipping data from Wakanda Server.

Is this a bug or is there something wrong with my code?

```
ds.Item.$query({start:5}).$promise.then(function(event) {
    $scope.tasks = event.result;
});
```

I am using Wakanda version 11.197492

Comment: What version of Angular-Wakanda are you using?

Comment: Blackus, I am using Wakanda version 11.197492

Comment: Your **Angular-Wakanda** version, not Wakanda. And, do you have any error message, or just the result without some being ignored (due to the `start` option)?

Comment: /*! angular-wakanda - v1.0.4 - 2016-02-23 */

Comment: Can you try with the latest 1.1.2 version of Angular-Wakanda?

Comment: when I using start options, there is nothing happen with my data. Just like not to use start options

Comment: https://github.com/Wakanda/angular-wakanda/releases you are brilliant Blackus. 1.1.2 version solve my problem. Thanks